# issue in retriving the height and width

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

I have developed an application in the blackberry in which it have to be build in any model of blackberry, the application in which i have developed does not show some icon which are in border, can any body help how to get the height and width of the mobile in the blackberry

Answer (score 1):

```
 int screenHeight = Display.getHeight();
 int screenWidth = Display.getWidth();
```

Comment: hi ViVart,

thanks for ur replay, i have implemented that in my program, i have an pop up screen in which i am displaying it by taking the x and y coordinates when i have displaying it the pop up is getting varied and not displaying correctly if i implemnted in different mobile

protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
  
   
  super.sublayout(mRectangle.width, mRectangle.height);
  setPosition(mRectangle.x-5, mRectangle.y);
  setExtent(mRectangle.width, mRectangle.height);
  }


and this is my code for displaying the pop up